# Missing vertical line in multirow table

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to make a table, but some vertical lines are missing. Could someone help me to see the mistake?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\parindent0em
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\cline{2-8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Generacion} & Nombre & Simbolo & Masa(eV) & Espin & Carga($e$) & Color \\ \cline{1-8} 

\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{3}{*}{Quarks} } & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}& \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
&\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
&\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{1-8} 
\cline{1-8} 

\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{3}{*}{Leptones} } & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{1-8} 
\cline{1-8} 


\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{Bosones}} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\          
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{3-8}
\cline{1-8} 

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is how the table looks]

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An important issue not mentioned in your posting is that the table is *too wide* to fit inside the text block. This may be remedied by (i) placing the units in two of the header cells in a separate row and (ii) reducing the value of `\tabcolsep`, the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace, by a third (from `6pt` to `4pt`.

The table code is, I hope you don't mind the criticism, rather cluttered. It may be simplified considerably by (a) setting the structure via

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
```

and (b) getting rid of the multitude of `\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}` directives. Do also replace all `\cline{1-8}` directives with `\hline` and drop the three redundant `\cline` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\parindent0em
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt

\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}} 
\cline{2-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& Generacion & Nombre & Simbolo & Masa & Espin & Carga  & Color \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& & & & (eV) & ($e$) &  & \\
\hline 
\multirow{3}{*}{Quarks} & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} 
                       & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
&                      & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\cline{2-8}
& \multirow{2}{*}{2a}  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
&                      & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\cline{2-8} 
& \multirow{2}{*}{3a}  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
&                      & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\hline 
\multirow{3}{*}{Leptones} & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} 
                       & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
&                      & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\cline{2-8}
& \multirow{2}{*}{2a}  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
&                      & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\cline{2-8} 
& \multirow{2}{*}{3a}  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
&                      & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\hline  
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{Bosones}} 
                       & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\          
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\hline 

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

Optional: All these vertical and horizontal lines do *not* contribute to the table's legibility and intelligibility; I would assume that these two criteria are important to your work. Dropping all vertical lines, replacing the `\cline` instructions with a bit of (vertical) whitespace, and using the rule-drawing macros (`\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`) of the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package gives you the following look -- I hope you will agree that it looks at least as good as the table above:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\parindent0em
\usepackage{multirow,array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{7}{c}@{}} 
\toprule 
& Generacion & Nombre & Simbolo & Masa & Espin & Carga  & Color \\ 
& & & & (eV) & ($e$) &  & \\
\midrule 
\multirow{3}{*}{Quarks}  & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \addlinespace
& \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \addlinespace 
& \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
&{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\midrule 
\multirow{3}{*}{Leptones}  & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\addlinespace
& \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\addlinespace 
 & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\midrule  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{5}{*}{Bosones}} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
&  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\          
&  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
&  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\addlinespace
&  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

if you really want vertical lines - it is not recommended - and get rid of the unneeded `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}`s.

[image: lines]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \cline{2-8} \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Generacion} & Nombre & Simbolo & Masa(eV) & Espin & Carga($e$) & Color \\ \cline{1-8}

\multirow{3}{*}{Quarks}  & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
&  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8}
& \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8}
 & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{1-8}

\multirow{3}{*}{Leptones}  & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8}
 & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8}
 & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{1-8}


\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{Bosones}} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{3-8}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I would, however, urge you to reconsider your presentation. I highly recommend taking a look at `booktabs` documentation on creating professional quality tables.

A quick makeover:

[image: made-over table]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
  \toprule & Generacion & Nombre & Simbolo & Masa(eV) & Espin & Carga($e$) & Color \\\midrule

  \multirow{3}{*}{Quarks}  & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  &  & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cmidrule{2-8}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cmidrule{2-8}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  \midrule

  \multirow{3}{*}{Leptones}  & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cmidrule{2-8}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cmidrule{2-8}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{5}{*}{Bosones}} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cmidrule{3-8}
  & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: In the version with the vertical rules, I'd also get rid of the redundant `\cline{1-8}` and `\cline{3-8}` directives (three in all) and replace the remaining `\cline{1-8}` statements with `\hline`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I meant to do that and must have forgotten to go back.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advice. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Here you are. The following code proposes two versions for this table.

– First, a table with horizontal and all vertical rules, slightly improved (cells in the first column are vertically centred).

– Then a solution without vertical rules, and much fewer horizontal rules, based on `booktabs`, resulting in a simpler code, and much better looking, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\parindent0em
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
%\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|Sc|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \cline{2-8}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Generacion} & Nombre & Simbolo & Masa(eV) & Espin & Carga($e$) & Color \\ \cline{1-8}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirowcell{6}[-5pt]{Quarks}} & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{ c| }{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{2-8}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c |}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{2-8}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c| }{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{1-8}
  \cline{1-8}

  \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{6}{*}[-5pt]{Leptones} } & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                           & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{2-8}
   & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                           & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{2-8}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                           & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\ \cline{1-8}
  \cline{1-8}

  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{5}{*}[-5pt]{Bosones}} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{3-8}
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{3-8}
  \cline{1-8}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
  \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-8}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Generacion} & Nombre & Simbolo & Masa(eV) & Espin & Carga($e$) & Color \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-8}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirowcell{6}[-5pt]{Quarks}} & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
  \addlinespace
                                                      & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
  \addlinespace
                                                      & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-8}

  %
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}{*}[-5pt]{Leptones}} & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
  \addlinespace
                                                      & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
  \addlinespace
                                                      & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-8}
  %
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{5}{*}[-5pt]{Bosones}} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
  \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
                                                      & & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 \\
  \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{3-8}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I find this a bit confusing. You start by saying you are proposing a solution with features X and Y but then immediately provide a solution which has neither of them. Then you provide a second solution which does, indeed, have both X and Y. Wondered if you might want to include some more sign-posting.

Comment: @cfr: ??? For me, I first solved the problem as posed by the O.P., then suggested (like all of us) a better solution based on `booktabs`. Anyway, I added some explanations to make that clearer. Is it less confusing now?

Comment: Yes, I find that much clearer. (+1) but I think you mean 'fewer horizontal rules' ;).

Comment: @cfr: Apparently I forgot some subtleties of English grammar…;o( Corrected, thank you.

Comment: It is a pet peeve. However, it will probably count as correct soon because the BBC now says things like 'less people' but they probably don't mean an equal number of smaller or lighter people.

Comment: We have the same problem in France. When I was in high school, our teachers objurgated some of us for  ‘writing like a journalist’…

Comment: My parents would take strong exception to that comparison ;). (Both retired newspaper journalists.)

Comment: Let's say French journalists…

Answer (score 1):

you need `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}` in first column

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\parindent0em
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\cline{2-8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Generacion} & Nombre & Simbolo & Masa(eV) & Espin & Carga($e$) & Color \\ \cline{1-8} 

\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{3}{*}{Quarks} } & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}& \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}& \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}&\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}&\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{1-8} 
\cline{1-8} 

\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{3}{*}{Leptones} } & \multirow{2}{*}{1a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & \multirow{2}{*}{2a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{2-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & \multirow{2}{*}{3a} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\  
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}& & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{1-8} 
\cline{1-8} 


\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{Bosones}} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\          
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & UP & 2 & 0 & 1 &5& 5\\ \cline{3-8}
\cline{1-8} 

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### `&` were missing

I had the same problem, when I added another column to my `multirow` `multicolumn` table. The new column was missing the vertical line in some rows.

[image]

I realized that in creating the table **I forgot to add `&` in all "placeholder rows"**. It resolved the issue.

[image]

**Usually build would complain about such a missing `&` and stop building**, but these tables seem more complex and error resistant.

### Summary

These  `multirow` `multicolumn`  get hard to overlook and a "placeholder row" in one column, may be a regular row in another.

Comment: I believe forgetting `&` would result in missing `|` on the right side, but not on the left, which OP seems to have.  (And omitting `&` won't cause an error.)

Comment: Referring to the first statement and the headline, I found it a matching response, as this happened to me but to the right side and others might end up here for the same reason.

My experience is, that omitting an & leads to latex stopping to build